# .htaccess select desktop or mobile folder

Tags: php, android, apache, .htaccess

I'm struggling with my htaccess to show the right version of my website.
We bought a Webiste from an agency and they gave us 3 folders.

Basically we have something like this:

- Pages/desktop/*
- Pages/mobile/*
- Pages/tablet/*

The * represents a list of folders like

- home
- services
- etc.

All of the folders contains the same list but with different files.

I need to render in mobile devices the Pages/mobile/ and with desktop devices the desktop one, both controlled by a single file.

I worked with .htaccess and made it work for mobile and for desktop, but not for both in the same file:

**This works really well for mobile. It calls the Pages/mobile/ and then sets a clean url with the /home content in the base url:**

```
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /Pages/mobile/$1
RewriteRule ^$ /home [L]
```

**This works really well for desktop. It calls the Pages/desktop/ and then sets a clean url with the /home content in the base url:**

```
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /Pages/desktop/$1
RewriteRule ^$ /home [L]
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, there is no available information in the web to resolve this problem.

**My try went something like this**

```
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android" [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /Pages/mobile/$1
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /Pages/desktop/$1
RewriteRule ^$ /home [L]
```

It is supposed to work, but I always get an error 500 or 403, in which it states `.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters`

Any ideas?

Comment: IMO the agency should be telling you how to configure their product correctly

Comment: I should... but is depend on people that think in files for mobile website instead of media queries... this guys might not know how to do it. I'm almost there without their help.

Comment: But if you bought it from them with these different folders then they should be able to tell you how to set it up correctly

Comment: Told them yesterday and they don't know... They are with the idea of doing m.mywebsite.com (mobile) and www.website.com (desktop). This is giving up in the htaccess idea, but I' sure there is a way.

Comment: Oh that's a concept from 10 years ago they're suggesting. They are very out of date

Comment: I know... I don't to through away the design i bought, that is why I need to tell when to render one folder or another. I'm almost there [S=1] is a rule that tells to omit the next rule.

All the RewriteCond works for setting mobile folder, but i can't set the desktop if the conds are not valid. Any idea?